# What happens to the "original" field under a field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I'm working out of Hungerford's (undergrad) algebra book. Extension fields are defined in a discussion on the structure of $F[x]/(p(x))$, where $p(x)$ is prime in $F[x]$:

"Let $F$ be a field and $p(x)$ an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$. Let $K$ denote the field of congruence classes $F[x]/(p(x))$. Then $F$ is a subfield of the field $K$ (equivalently: $K$ is an extension field of $F$)."

This concept is introduced to show that irreducible polynomials $f(x)$ in $F[x]$ have roots when considered as polynomials over $K$.

My question is, how can I understand how the original field "behaves" inside of the extension field? Vaguely speaking, does $K$ contain a copy (or an isomorphic copy) of $F$ plus some other "stuff?" Must every property satisfied by $F$ (commutative, inverse, etc.) carry over to the copy of $F$ in $K$?

Finally, is it possible for there to exist an element $u$ in $F$ and an element $w$ in $K$ (and not in the part that's isomorphic to $F$) s.t. $uw = 1_F$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is a canonical projection $\pi: F[x] \to F[x]/(p(x))$ and when restricted to $F$, this gives a homomorphism $F \to K$. Note that it preserves the $1 \in F$ so it is a nonzero map of fields. Therefore, it must be injective. This shows we can identify $F$ with the subfield $\pi (F) \subseteq K$ which will be an isomorphic copy of $F$ contained in $K$. The properties you mention, such as commutativity and inverse are always preserved under isomorphisms.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The field extension $K$ does contain an isomorphic copy of $F$, and usually, we do not even make a distinction between the isomorphic copy of $F$ in $K$ and $F$ itself.  In this case, we just think of $F$ as a subfield of K i.e. $ F \subseteq K$. So every (first-order) property that holds in $F$ will also hold in the isomorphic copy of $F$ contained in K.

As for your question about the $u \in F$, I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  Since $F$ is a field, every element has an inverse.

Comment: Great! Appreciate it. About the last part, tho, I meant to say: is it possible to have u in F and w in K (and not the part that's isomorphic to F) where uw=1?

Comment: Sure, no problem.  And no that wouldn't be possible.  If $uw =1$ in $K$ then $u$ could not be $0$.  Hence, $u$ is a nonzero element of $F$ and since $F$ is a field, $u$ has an inverse $u^{-1}$.  But inverses are unique, so we must have $w = u^{-1} \in F$.

Comment: So, in $K$, $u$ essentially has "two" inverses, one in $F$ and the other in $K$ (and not in $F$). But since $K$ is a field and inverses are unique, these two elements must be the same; hence, $w$ is in$F$.

Comment: That's mostly the idea, yes. I'm not sure I would say $u$ has "two inverses" though. We just use "w" to conclude that "u" is invertible and because of this "w" must be "u^{-1}".

Comment: Oh, sure. I wouldn't say that in a write-up! Thanks again.